# How to create a task with Type "Action" in workflow rule

Tags: workflow, process-builder, time-dependent-workflow

I have a workflow rule on Quote Object where I have defined a Time-Dependent Workflow Actions which creates a task 3 days before Quote: Expiration Date.The rule is working fine, but when this workflow is creating task the Type field is being defaulted to blank.The Type field is not available when I create a task while defining Time-Dependent Workflow Actions.I have to set the Type field to 'Action' while creating task.

I have also created this workflow rule in process builder, but there as well, I cannot find Type field in Scheduled Actions while creating a task.

is it possible to update Type field without using code?is there a way I can achieve it using process builder?

Comment: Hey can please check once again in process builder like  Type AND  Call Type in process builder. @sfdcdev

Comment: You can find in the process builder. But you can not find this field using work flow.

Answer (score 1):

Hey please check till end of the list in process builder you get type field like.

For reference:

[image]

Comment: When I type 'Type' in Field search box, I am getting Call Type, Recurrence Type, and Task Subtype

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of yours.@sfdcdev